# How do I access the text in a UILabel IBOutlet from another controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

MY program is a simple calculator. The main view is hooked up to the CalcViewController.h/.m On the bottom of the calculator there's the top 100 points of a subview showing with a button on it. When the user clicks on the subview button that is showing, the rest of the subview slides up to the bottom of the label, where the input numbers are showing. The subview (AdvancedView) only has one other button on it right now (sqrt). When this is pressed I would like to get the numbers that are currently in the label and send them to the model to perform the square root method on them. The only problem that I'm having is that the UILabel IBOutlet *display is set in my CalViewController, not my AdvancedView where I also need it. Ive tried Importing the CalcViewController.h into my AdvancedView.h and then synthesizing a *mainView pointer to CalcViewController but when I call

```
    double currentText = [self.mainView.display.text doubleValue];
```

from within my Advanced view, if there's a number in the display is still get 0.000000. I've also searched the net a lot for solutions and keep coming across protocols but I can't seem to completely wrap my head around this concept. So back to my question: How do I access the text in a UILabel IBOutlet *display from another controller class? Here is the code I'm working with:

CalcViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CalcViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *display;
@end
```

CalcViewController.m

```
#import "CalcViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"
#import "AdvancedView.h"

@interface CalcViewController()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AdvancedView *myNewView;
@end

@implementation CalcViewController
@synthesize display = _display;
@synthesize userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = _userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping;
@synthesize brain = _brain;
@synthesize myNewView = _myNewView;
- (AdvancedView *) myNewView
{
    if (!_myNewView) _myNewView = [[AdvancedView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 489, 320, 200)];
    return _myNewView;
}
- (void)setMyNewView:(AdvancedView *)myNewView
{
    NSLog(@"what the duece");
}
- (void)subView
{
    int advancedTag = 199998;
    self.myNewView.tag = advancedTag;

    if (![self.view viewWithTag:advancedTag]) {
        [self.view addSubview:self.myNewView];

    } 
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Show the top 100 of AdvancedView
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self subView];

    CGRect newFrame = self.myNewView.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = 480-75;
    self.myNewView.frame = newFrame;
    NSString *testText = self.display.text;
    NSLog(@"The test text is %@", testText);

}
- (CalculatorBrain *)brain
{
    if (!_brain) _brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    return _brain;
}
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping)
    {
        self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
    } else {
        self.display.text = digit;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = YES;
    }
}
- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.brain pushOperandOne:[self.display.text doubleValue]];
    [self.brain pushOperator:sender.currentTitle];
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = NO;
}
- (IBAction)enterPressed {
    [self.brain pushOperandTwo:[self.display.text doubleValue]];
    // self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = NO;
    double result = [self.brain execute];
    NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
    self.display.text = resultString;

}
- (IBAction)clear {
    self.display.text = @"0";
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = NO;
    [self.brain cleadLastCalculatedValue];
}
@end
```

AdvancedView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AdvancedView : UIView
@end
```

AdvancedView.m

```
#import "AdvancedView.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"
#import "CalcViewController.h"

@interface AdvancedView()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL toggleTheView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CalculatorBrain *subBrain;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CalcViewController *mainView;
@end

@implementation AdvancedView
@synthesize toggleTheView = _toggleTheView;
@synthesize subBrain = _subBrain;
@synthesize mainView = _mainView;

- (CalcViewController *)mainView
{
    if (!_mainView) _mainView = [[CalcViewController alloc] init];
    return _mainView;
}
- (CalculatorBrain *)subBrain
{
    if (!_subBrain) _subBrain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    return _subBrain;
}
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:rect]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(display:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button setTitle:@"Advanced features" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 10.0, 160.0, 40.0);
        [self addSubview:button];

        // sqrt button
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

        UIButton *sqrt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        [sqrt addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(squareIt:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [sqrt setTitle:@"sqrt" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        sqrt.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 60.0, 160.0, 40.0);

        [self addSubview:sqrt];



    }
    return self;
}

- (void) squareIt:(id)sender
{
    double currentText = [self.mainView.display.text doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"%f", currentText);
    double result = [self.subBrain squareRoot:[self.mainView.display.text doubleValue]];
    NSLog(@"the text is: %f", result);
    NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
    self.mainView.display.text = resultString;
}

- (void) display:(id)sender
{
    if (!_toggleTheView) {

        float bottomYOfDigitToBeDisplayed = 75;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, bottomYOfDigitToBeDisplayed, 320, 400);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.toggleTheView = YES;

    } else {
        float bottomYOfDigitToBeDisplayed = 405;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, bottomYOfDigitToBeDisplayed, 320, 400);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.toggleTheView = NO;
    }

}
@end
```

Note: I didn't want to take up anymore screen with the model class so I just keft it out. It's just a typical model.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing right now is making a new view of CalcViewController in AdvancedView

to sum it up in easy language.

1. you made a view of CalcViewController .. lets say A
2. then in AdvancedView you make a new CalcViewController(_mainView)
   lets say B
3. what you want is value of text in A .. but you are getting value of
   B..whose display label does not have a value..

What you need to do is make the CalcViewController a singleton..

that is only make one object of CalcViewController in the app lifetime.

**in CalcViewController.m add  before the #import statements**

```
 static CalcViewController *view;
```

**then add a method (declared in .h file...defined in m)**

```
+ (CalcViewController *) getCalcViewController;
{
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[CalcViewController alloc] init];
    }

    return view;
}
```

now just use

```
double currentText = [[CalcViewController getCalcViewController].display.text doubleValue];
```

Comment: The first part of your answer makes perfect sense now. But I added static CalcViewController *view to above the imports and I got error: unknown type name. I then declared the getCalcViewController class method to my advancedView.h and I got error: Expected a type. And when I defined getCalcViewController in .m I get error: Use of undefined identifier 'view'. As far as the 'view' error goes I'm guessing I need to declare that property in my AdvancedView. What about those other errors?

Comment: okay ..add static CalcViewController *view after the import statements in  CalcViewController.m i confused it with native iOS data types.. do that..and follow the rest of the steps on my answer

Comment: Ok, I got rid of all the errors but when I enter 9 into the label, hit the advanced features button to bring up AdvancedView and hit sqrt button, 0.000 is stil being assigned to currentText:

Comment: double currentText = [[CalcViewController getCalcViewController].display.text doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"%f", currentText);

Comment: before double currentText = ..... try to update its value.... that is do opposite ..change its text and then get the value.. see if it is still 0.0

Comment: I can't seem to capture that value. I've tried many variation of this: CalcViewController *calc = [CalcViewController getCalcViewController];
    double cD = [calc.display.text doubleValue];
    cD = [calc.display.text doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"%@", cD);